# Jenkins + Maven Wagon SSH-External - Incompatiblity?

Tags: maven, jenkins, maven-wagon-plugin

We were using the Maven SSH Wagon but because of a bug in Jsch (Java Secure Channel) 1.5.0 (Dependency of Maven SSH Wagon) we switched to SSH-External Wagon 2.8 to avoid the usage of Jsch.

With Maven SSH-External Wagon a mvn deploy call from the command line succeeds, but using Jenksing and the Jenkins Maven Plugin ('Deploy artifacts to Maven repository' post-build action) the deployment fails:

```
Caused by: org.apache.maven.wagon.TransferFailedException: Exit code: 1 - /bin/sh: line 0: cd: /<path-to-jenkins-job>/modules/<maven-group-id>/builds/2015-02-05_13-27-35/archive/<maven-group-id>/<maven-artifact-id>/0.94-SNAPSHOT: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
```

Jenkins saves the module artifact under `/<path-to-jenkins-job>/modules/<maven-group-id>**$**<maven-artifact-id>/builds/2015-02-05_13-27-35/archive/<maven-group-id>/<maven-artifact-id>/0.94-SNAPSHOT`

Is the dollar sign in the path the problem for Maven SSH-External Wagon?

Answer (score 0):

This has been fixed in Jenkins 1.609 (or some version before).